# Try-catch did'nt catched the error thrown from .then().catch()

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm tring to create an Auth service for my application. I have throwed the error from the .then().catch(), but it did'nt catched by the try-catch.

```
async logIn(
        req: Request,
        res: Response,
        next: NextFunction
    ): Promise<Response<any, Record<string, any>>> {
        try {
            const { userName, password } = req.body;
            const user = await this.userService.getUserByPassword(
                userName,
                password
            );

            if (user) {
                const userData: UserData = {
                    id: user.id,
                    email: user.email,
                    firstName: user.firstName,
                    lastName: user.lastName,
                    userName: user.userName
                };

                this.authService
                    .generateAccessToken(userData, ROLE.admin)
                    .then((accessToken) => {
                        return res.cookie('token', accessToken).json(userData);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        // thrown from here
                        throw err;
                    });
            }
        } catch (err) {
            const error = errorHandler(err);

            return res.status(400).send(error);
        }
    }
```

anyone could explain why this happend?

Comment: If you want to catch the error thrown from that particular `catch` block, you need to add another `catch` block to the chain.

Comment: @zx01 thank you for your reply, I just wanted to catch it by the try-catch that wraps the then-catch

Comment: inside your then.catch function., try throwing a new instance of the error. e.g `throw new Error(err.mesage)`. Although @zx01 is correct too.